# How to extend convoy volume?

Tags: docker

Environment:

- CentOS 7.4.1708
- Docker 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
- convoy v0.5.0 (docker-convoy: Docker volume plugin) with devicemapper

Phase 1: Created convoy volume

```
sudo convoy create data-test --size 100M
```

Phase 2: Tried to extend convoy volume

1. Backup original convoy volume
2. Restore volume with `--size` option
   Then, I got an error that Volume must be same size.

Is there way to extend convoy volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker-convoy uses devicemapper(default) that user could visible to block-device(try `lsblk`).

1. Create new volume with `--size` option:

   `sudo convoy create new-volume-name --size 1000G`
2. Transfer data from `volume-name` to `new-volume-name`:

   `sudo dd if=/dev/mapper/volume-name of=/dev/mapper/new-volume-name`
3. Resize `new-volume-name`:

   `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/new-volume-name`

   If it warn need to check by e2fsck, run `sudo e2fsck /dev/mapper/new-volume-name`
4. Check volume that it is readable:

   `sudo convoy mount new-volume-name`

   `sudo ls -l /var/lib/rancher/convoy/devicemapper/mounts/new-volume-name`

   `sudo convoy umount new-volume-name`
5. Remove original volume:

   `sudo convoy delete volume-name`
6. Switch from `volume-name` to `new-volume-name` at the container.

Note:
This process is for offline migration. I could not find out incremental backup in this time. Before you run this, the docker containers should be stopped.
And, there is no way to rename volume name.